# Calculating Percentage in C#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, percentage

What am I missing here while attempting to calculate the percentage complete?  My percentage equation seems to return an incorrect percentage.

```
Int32 counter = 0;

foreach (var vehicle in vehicles)
{
    counter += 1;

    Int32 percentage = (Int32)((double)counter * vehicles.Count()) / 100;

    _worker.ReportProgress(percentage);


    if (_worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        _worker.ReportProgress(0);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: "My percentage equation seems to return an incorrect percentage." What input values give what output value, and what did you expect? Can you rewrite this as a short but complete console app? (It should be trivial to do so.)

Comment: Why are you multiplying counter by the count and not dividing?  I think you are a little backwards in your formula there...

Comment: iMortalitySX, you're right.  I got it a little backwards.  :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To work out percentages you should be doing

```
progress
--------  x 100
 total
```

You are doing

```
progress x total
----------------
       100
```

Try using `(counter * 100) / vehicles.Count()` instead.

Note: If you do the multiplication by 100 before the division it means you don't need to mess about with casts to floats / doubles, however it does mean that all of your percentages are rounded down.  If you want a more precise percentage then cast to doubles and don't worry about the order.

Comment: Yeah, it dawned on me that this is the correct route.  I didn't sleep enough last night I think.  :)

Comment: If I have 1, 4, 1 and I try to get percentage using `Math.Round()`, I end up getting 17%, 67%, 17% which totals to 101%. How would I fix that?

Answer (score 9):

how about

```
     Int32 percentage = counter * 100 / vehicles.Count();
```

Comment: +1 but don't forget to check for Count() != 0 (or vehicles != null for that matter).

Comment: as it is within the foreach loop, Count is always > 0 if the code within the loop is executed

Comment: LOL, you are correct, I just meant as a general case, you would check these.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :-

```
  int percentage= (int)( ((100f * counter) / vehicles.count()));
```

Cast to float to avoid integer division giving you a zero, and you can add 0.5 for integer rounding. Use 0.5f not 0.5 to keep it from expanding to double ie

```
  int percentage= (int)(0.5f + ((100f * counter) / vehicles.count()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Math.round():

```
Int32 percentage = (Int32)Math.Round( (double)(counter * 100) / vehicles.Count());
```

Comment: If I have 1, 4, 1 and I try to get percentage using `Math.Round()`, I end up getting 17%, 67%, 17% which totals to 101%. How would I fix that?

Comment: You are losing information before you make your sum; you must carry more precision before you make a total or else you can't expect your subsequent calculations to maintain significant correctness. e.g. In your example keeping one decimal place by using Math.Round(x,1) will result in a sum of 100.1 which will round to 100.